# What are the main pros and cons of the GeneCafe coffee roaster?

Tags: roasting, home-roasting, specific-machine

Having never roasted coffee, I would like to start roasting coffee at home (I'm UK-based). Due to time, and other constraints, I am looking for a solution that requires as little human intervention as possible.

I was thinking of getting a [GeneCafe CBR-101 Coffee Roaster](https://www.amazon.co.uk/GeneCafe-CBR-101-Coffee-Roaster-Red/dp/B01A5OJLM8/). Considering that they're not cheap (£583 at time of writing), I would like to know what the machine's main pros and con are.

Comment: Welcome to Coffee! I've rephrased it to be more of an objective question. Asking for user's opinions and experiences is too opinion-based for Q&A on Stack Exchange. Instead, asking about the main advantages and disadvantages of this specific machine is probably narrow enough. Also seeing that the machine is fairly well known and others might have this question too, I think it's one worth asking. :)

Comment: Thank you, @JJJ